I can't get axi data from vxworks6.9！（base on zynq7045）
I made a BSP of vxworks6.9 on the PS side of zynq7045, and now I need to do the following:

First, I need to malloc 4k memory on vxworks, and put the first address of its physical address on 0x43c00000 + 0x4 (this address is provided by the IP core on the PL side)
After receiving the address, the PL side will place the 4k bytes of data at the physical address I provided. After placing it, it will send me an interrupt (61)
I take the 4k bytes of data from the physical address and perform other operations.
I wrote a single-core test program on vivado SDK, and it worked well. But when I wrote the program on vxworks using the same process, there was a problem. After receiving the interrupt, I could not see the data at the physical address, all locations were 0x0 as I initialized.
In the 32 bit-width BSP, I enabled CACHE and MMU, but did not enable SMP.
And in sysLib.c, I mapped 1G space start from 0x40000000.
At the same time, I also modified the memory mapping. It now looks like this:

PHYS_MEM_DESC sysPhysMemDesc[] = 
...
    {
    LOCAL_MEM_LOCAL_ADRS,    /* virtual address */
    LOCAL_MEM_LOCAL_ADRS,    /* physical address */
    ROM_BASE_ADRS - LOCAL_MEM_LOCAL_ADRS,
    MMU_ATTR_VALID_MSK | MMU_ATTR_PROT_MSK | MMU_ATTR_DEVICE_SHARED_MSK,
#if defined( _WRS_CONFIG_SMP) || defined(INCLUDE_ACP) /* needs to be shared */
    MMU_ATTR_VALID     | MMU_ATTR_SUP_RWX  | MMU_ATTR_CACHE_DEFAULT
    | MMU_ATTR_CACHE_COHERENCY
#else
    MMU_ATTR_VALID | MMU_ATTR_SUP_RWX | MMU_ATTR_DEVICE_SHARED
#endif /* _WRS_CONFIG_SMP || INCLUDE_ACP */
    },
...

I'm a tyro on vxworks, what should i do to get the data from PL??
At first, i think it's because cache. i dont know how to disable mmu/cache in bsp, so i check cachelib and use cacheInvalidate() for try. but it doesnt works.
i also use wdb to verify whether the address is given to PL (0x43c00000). it turely did.
during hanging in interrupt (wdb), i tryed use "d 0x2a78020" to view memory. it's also all 0.
I have spent three days on this problem. please help me.
memory_watch
wdb_watch
P.S. I use the malloc() function to get the memory, I understand that the memory of vxworks6.9 is insinuated one by one, but I don't know whether I get real physical memory address, please help me figure out these confusions
